# Derive words from string based on key words

Tags: python

I have a string (text_string) from which I want to find words based on my so called key_words. I want to store the result in a list called expected_output.

The expected output is always the word after the keyword (the number of spaces between the keyword and the output word doesn't matter). The expected_output word is then all characters until the next space.

Please see the example below:

```
text_string = "happy yes_no!?.  why coding      without      paus happy yes"
key_words = ["happy","coding"]

expected_output = ['yes_no!?.', 'without', 'yes']

expected_output explanation: 
yes_no!?.        (since it comes after happy. All signs are included until the next space.)
without          (since it comes after coding. the number of spaces surronding the word doesn't matter)
yes              (since it comes after happy)
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: you can use `text_string.split()` to get list of all words in the `text_string`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve it using regex. Like this e.g.

```
import re


expected_output = re.findall('(?:{0})\s+?([^\s]+)'.format('|'.join(key_words)), text_string)
```

#### Explanation

1. **(?:{0})** Is getting your `key_words` list and creating a non-capturing group with all the words inside this list.
2. **\s+?** Add a lazy quantifier so it will get all spaces after any of the former occurrences up to the next character which isn't a space
3. **([^\s]+)** Will capture the text right after your `key_words` until a next space is found

**Note**: in case you're running this too many times, inside a loop i.e, you ought to use `re.compile` on the regex string before in order to improve performance.

Comment: `re.compile` is only required when many different regexes are used. By default, `re` module will compile regex and cache them (see https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.compile : "The compiled versions of the most recent patterns passed to re.compile() **and the module-level matching functions** are cached, so programs that use only a few regular expressions at a time needn’t worry about compiling regular expressions.")

Comment: I misunderstood that then. Thank you very much for the clarification @Guybrush :)

Answer (score 0):

We will use `re` module of Python to split your strings based on whitespaces. 
Then, the idea is to go over each word, and look if that word is part of your keywords. If yes, we set `take_it` to True, so that next time the loop is processed, the word will be added to `taken` which stores all the words you're looking for.

```
import re

def find_next_words(text, keywords):
  take_it = False
  taken = []
  for word in re.split(r'\s+', text):
    if take_it == True:
      taken.append(word)
    take_it = word in keywords
  return taken

print(find_next_words("happy yes_no!?.  why coding      without      paus happy yes", ["happy", "coding"]))
```

results in `['yes_no!?.', 'without', 'yes']`